# Short key Ctrl + - not working vb

Tags: vb.net, keyboard-shortcuts

I have the following code:

```
Private Sub myGrid_KeyDown(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As    System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventArgs) Handles myGrid.KeyDown
    If e.KeyCode = Keys.Divide AndAlso e.Control Then
        Dim response = MsgBox("are you sure to delete a record?", vbYesNo)
        If response = vbYes Then
            //Delete the record
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

This works (For <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>/</kbd>), but the problem is that this works for any key different than `-`. If I specify that the Keycode is Keys.Subtract (To use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>-</kbd>) it is never caught!

Answer (score 0):

The KeyCode for "-" is `Keys.OemMinus`.  Use `Debug.WriteLine(e.KeyCode.ToString())` to test what keys you are pressing.  The following works for me:

```
Private Sub myGrid_KeyDown(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventArgs) Handles myGrid.KeyDown
    If e.KeyCode = Keys.OemMinus AndAlso e.Control Then
        Dim response = MsgBox("are you sure to delete a record?", vbYesNo)
        If response = vbYes Then
            '//Delete the record
        End If
    End If
    Debug.WriteLine(e.KeyCode.ToString())
End Sub
```